# React Admin getOne doesnt work with Api Patform dataProvider

Tags: reactjs, react-admin, api-platform.com, hydra-core

I am building a CMS using **@api-platform** API on backend and with their **react admin** boilerplate. Using their **Hydra** **dataProvider** none of the Query methods of calling getOne doesn't seem to be working. I tried all hooks and also legacy  component or **useDataProvider.getOne**. The behavior is that the **GET URL is wrong generated**. It doesn't contain the **resource** path. Instead there is a **undefined** in the URL created.

```
<Query type="getOne" resource="videos" payload={{ id: '1000' }}>
    {({ data, loading, error }) => {
        if (loading) {
            return <Loading />;
        }
        if (error) {
            return <Error />;
        }
        return data.name;
    }}
</Query>;
```

Also using **useQuery**:

```
const { data, loading, error } = useQuery({ 
        type: 'getOne',
        resource: 'videos',
        payload: { id: "1000"}
    });
```

They are generating the following GET request:

`Request URL: https://ra-api.testing.company.com/undefined`
`Request Method: GET`

All other methods generate something like this:

`Request URL: https://ra-api.testing.company.com/api/videos`
`Request Method: GET`

The dataProvider looks like this:

```
export const dataProvider = baseHydraDataProvider(
    global.RA_API_ENTRYPOINT,
    fetchHydra,
    apiDocumentationParser
);
```

Other methods like getLists or update/create are working properly. Any ideea ?

Answer (score 2):

The Hydra data provider is not using the `resource` parameter for the `getOne` query, only the `id`:
https://github.com/api-platform/admin/blob/5badc1f19024c1800a60431e575219039b86d0b6/src/hydra/dataProvider.js#L227

It's because the `id` in the payload needs to be an **IRI**, like this:

```js
const { data, loading, error } = useQuery({ 
    type: 'getOne',
    resource: 'videos',
    payload: { id: '/videos/1000' },
});
```

With API Platform Admin (and the Hydra data provider), all identifiers are IRI.